# Django templating for loop working for the first item

Tags: python, django

Can't really find out what am doing wrongly !! I created a template that has a view and in that view I created a context dictionary which contain filtered orders for a specific user but for some reason in the template I created a loop for order details with a button which allows the user to see more order details but its working only for the first order item

my order model

```html
class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    date_ordered = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    total = models.FloatField(max_length=15,null=True, blank=True)
    shipping = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
    date_ordered = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    delivery = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="3-20 business days", blank=True, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

my view:

```html
@login_required(login_url="login")
 def user_Orders(request):
    user = request.user.customer
    orders = Order.objects.filter(customer=user).filter(complete=True)
    return render(request, 'shop/orders.html', {'orders':orders, "user":user})
```

my template

```html
<h3 style="color: #0457ae;padding-left: 40px;"><u>YOUR ORDERS</u></h3>
  {% for order in orders %}
      <p>Order total: ${{order.total}}</p>
      <p>Status: Paid</p>
      <p>Transaction id/tracking number :<span id="trans_id">&nbsp;{{order.transaction_id}}</span></p>
      <button id="myBtn" class="btn btn-outline-primary">more details</button>
      <div id="myModal" class="modal">
          <!-- Modal content -->
          <div class="modal-content">
              <span class="close">&times;</span>
              <center><u>More order details</u></center>
              <p>shipping to :{{order.shipping}}</p>
              <p>Estimated delivery: {{order.delivery}}</p>
              <p>phone: {{order.phone}}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
 </div>
```

the images below shows the output ... I want the popup to happen for each order but its working for the first one only

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HH3a.png]

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1AGj.png]

Comment: Can you just print `orders` in template without any tag to see if it has more than one element

Comment: How does the button know which order it should show details for..?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: well I thought by putting the button in the loop that way for each order there will be a button to access its details but maybe am wrong so thats why I need to highlight me

Comment: Do you use Bootstrap?

Comment: well printing the 'orders' variable prints out an ugly looking list of orders and yes it has more than one element coz I want the user to be able to make more than one order. what changes should I make ??

Answer (score 1):

Every modal needs a unique id, like @Pablo Estevez said.

So make sure you have a unique value in your `models.py`, (usually an id), that you have given in the context of your view.


With a unique id,
you can do something like:

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#{{something.id}}Modal">
```

To open a modal.


The modal code would look something like this (using bootstrap):

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="{{something.id}}Modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="detailsModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                      <div class="modal-dialog  modal-xl" style="width:100%" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                          <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="detailsModalLabel">Something here</h5>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                          </div>
                          <div class="modal-body">
                            <h6>Body with text</h6>
                          </div>
                          <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well !!! It didn't cross my mind to use the order id as a unique identifier for each particular order in this case but I think thats where I was getting it all wrong and started to look for problems where they aren't .... I knew what to do but I needed someone to open my mind I guess ........ Thanks Tim

Answer (score 0):

Its bad practice that all the buttons have the same id, and also they should have better mames.
So, if you change the id from myBtn to detailBtn{{order.id}} and the id for the modal to detailModal{{order.id}}, and edit the javascript you could do that clicking in detailBtnX change the class of detailModalX (change the x for the number)

Comment: Interesting!!!!!! Thanks alot Pablo !!!! Let me try but am sure giving the button the order id  will work